# Joining all object of one array into same array as per key

Tags: jquery, angularjs, underscore.js

I have this

```
[{"n1":{"0":"2"},"f1":{"0":3}},{"n1":{"1":"3"},"f1":{"1":2}}]
```

I want this

```
[{"n1":{"0":"2", "1":"3"},"f1":{"0":3, "1":2}}]
```

using underscore or Jquery.. Please guide...

Comment: Are you sure you're putting it correctly? That looks like an input of array with two object, with the output of array with one object. This isn't outputting an array with keys.

Comment: @rrd yeah looked weird to me too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pull this out with pure JS using the ultimate [**`reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) (I fondly call it one-function army) and a bunch of `for-in`s. Something like this:

```js
let arr = [{"n1":{"0":"2"},"f1":{"0":3}},{"n1":{"1":"3"},"f1":{"1":2}}]

let modified = arr.reduce((res, objs) => {
  for (let key in objs) {
    res[key] = res[key] || {}
    for (let i in objs[key]) {
      res[key][i] = objs[key][i]
    }
  }
  return res
}, {})

let result = [modified]

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @AsadAliKhan glad that helped! :)

Comment: One more help

how to change [{0: "1", 1: "2"}] to ["1","2"]

Comment: @AsadAliKhan sure, hard to explain here in comments.. can you put up a new question.. you can send the question link here if you want.. this way if I can't find a solution, at least someone else will